# The louder he talked of his honor, the faster we counted our spoons

Tags: meaning

> The louder he talked of his honor, **the faster we counted our spoons.**

What does "the faster we counted our spoons" mean in the citation above?

Comment: I think there is an extra element in this quote: the idea that something bad is going to happen soon, which is why they count faster.

Comment: They counted faster because with every word he said, they were more convinced that he was a thief. The counting may have been half-hearted when there was just a soupçon of suspicion, but became more serious as the time approached when he might actually get away.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The Ralph Waldo Emerson [quote](http://quotationsbook.com/quote/19377/) in your question riffs off the idiom *to count one's spoons* meaning, as others have noted, to check and make sure that 
nothing has been stolen by suspicious guests. The [phrase](http://books.google.com/books?id=po8EAQAAIAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=life%20of%20johnson%20boswell&hl=en&ei=BT4KTsDCI4P20gHqvsls&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CD8Q6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=count%20our%20spoons&f=false) can be traced back 
to James Boswell's *[Life of Samuel Johnson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Boswell#Boswell.27s_Life_of_Samuel_Johnson)*, 1791:

[image: http://books.google.com/books?id=po8EAQAAIAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=life+of+johnson+boswell&hl=en&ei=BT4KTsDCI4P20gHqvsls&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CD8Q6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=count%20our%20spoons&f=false]

**Edit (5/4/12):** Note this passage has been turned up 23 years earlier in another Boswell book. See Hugo's link in the comment below.

Comment: The very same Johnson quote is in Boswell's [1768](http://books.google.fi/books?id=yRAQAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA335&dq=%22count+our+spoons%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=LoijT4e-O-Go4gTvxYlO&redir_esc=y#v=thumbnail&q=%22count%20our%20spoons%22&f=false) *An account of Corsica*.

Comment: Good catch. Noted.

Answer (score 9):

The spoons being alluded to are no doubt silverware, and are a candidate for theft. I.e., the more he talked about being virtuous, the more certain they were that he was a crook.

Comment: Has he not seen Les Misérables?

Answer (score 3):

The saying is missing an intermediate phrase, which is understood. (I put it in parentheses)

1) "The more he talked of his honor" 2(the more suspicious he was and sounded like a thief)
3) then follows "the more we counted our spoons" (silverware) to make sure they were still there.

Answer (score 1):

My family adored Emerson. I have always  taken the saying as meaning, since most families in the U.S. at the time, counted silver spoons as among their most valuable possessions (we have some, nearly transparent with wear),it means the louder one speaks of such as patriotism, the more doubtful we are about the speaker's sincerity as a patriot in the true sense. Very handy for casting doubt in a jocular fashion on reported remarks.